# Adding head node to singly linked list gives segmentation fault error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I started writing this very simple function in C to add node to a singly link list at the head. Here is my function. `head` parameter is pointer to the first node of the linked list. It can come as `NULL` if linked list is empty. `data` is the number to be put in data field of the new node to be added:

```
Node* InsertAtHead(Node *head, int data)
{
    Node newHeadNode;
    newHeadNode.data = data;
    newHeadNode.next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = &newHeadNode;
    }
    else
    {
        newHeadNode.next = head;
        head = &newHeadNode;
    }

    return head;
}
```

Definition of Head is as below:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

This works on my machine but not on my colleague's machine. At the other machine the program gives segmentation fault error. What is wrong in my function?

Comment: Dont you think you need to allocate space for `newHeadNode`?

Comment: @SMA will that not happen on its own?

Comment: ohhh! I think that gives me some clue @user3121023 . `newHeadNode` will get allocated on stack since it is local to the function but will get lost once function scope is gone.

Comment: This is not your code..`Node* ..` won't compile! it should be `struct Node* ..` unless there is a `typedef` you are not showing in the question.

Comment: @ThunderWiring it is compiling successfully in the current state without defining any `typedef`. The reason being I'm using a C++ project template to run my C code. Unfortunately, Visual Studio doesn't support any C language specific project template. So I'm forced to write my C language program in *.cpp files.

Comment: Maybe your IDE knows how to deal with this.
Also, according to correct 'grammar', there is no type called `Node`, there is `struct Node` however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns the address of a local variable with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*) `newHeadNode`.  Using this in the rest of the program invokes undefined behavior.  You should instead allocate the node with `malloc()` and return the pointer to the allocated object:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

Node *InsertAtHead(Node *head, int data) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node != NULL) {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = head;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Remember to store the return value into the heap pointer of the list unless it is NULL. An alternate safer API is this:

```
Node *InsertAtHead(Node **head, int data) {
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node != NULL) {
        node->data = data;
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;  // update the head pointer
    }
    return node;
}
```

With this API, you pass the address of the head pointer, which only gets updated if allocation succeeds.

Comment: I am getting few compilation errors in first line of your first code snippet. I changed it to `Node *node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
` to make it work.

Comment: Your compiler might be configured as a C++ compiler.  The cast is not necessary and considered counter-productive in C.  Do you include `<stdlib.h>`?

Comment: But for writing C Programs in Visual Studio there is no specific way I believe. I simply use new C++ console project template wizard. There is no project template specific to C projects in Visual Studio. I simply write my C programs in code files having *.cpp extension. As long as I'm restricting myself to using structs, pointers etc it is as good as a C program. Essentially I refrain from using C++ constructs like new operator.

Comment: @RBT: I did suspect you were using Microsoft tools, and I understand the constraints.  Be aware that C++ and C are different languages, even if you restrict yourself to the subset of C++ that looks like C.  You can try enclosing your C code in a `extern "C" {` ... `}` block to force the compiler to use C semantics, but Visual Studio is not a C99 compliant compiler / library combination.  You can also install cygwin or a linux virtual machine to get a *real* C environment.

Comment: Interesting indeed! I got some details of this extern stuff [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c). I'll try Ubuntu on an unallocated partition on my hard drive if that's the case. Cheers!

Comment: I enclosed my entire main function inside an `extern "C" {...}` block but then it starts giving error `'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'Node *` if I don't use the cast for pointer. In the line `Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));` you have put the asterisk sign before `node` variable. Is that correct?

Comment: @RBT: yes, that's correct. Your C++ compiler cannot behave exactly like a C compiler.  This difference is not significant here as you can fix it by adding the cast.  `void*` pointers cannot be converted implicitly to other pointer types in C++.

Comment: I was able to reach bit closer to `C` specific code compilation. Every C++ project in Visual Studio has a setting `Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As`. I set this option to `Compile As C Code (/TC)`. Now I don't require the pointer casting as you had advised earlier. Now this piece of code `Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));` works as is for me as well. Hurrah!

Comment: @RBT: good find! also change the extension from `.cpp` to `.c` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have used a local variable for the new node, which will become invalid on function exit. There is also no need to make a separate condition when `head == NULL`.

```
Node* InsertAtHead(Node *head, int data)
{
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);   // note: check the pointer
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = head;
    return newNode;
}
```